# How to set a dynamic length in laravel-nova?

Tags: php, laravel, rules, laravel-nova

I am using Nova in laravel for designing the page,i am writing some rules function which will allows `digits:20` .

```
 Text::make('TrackID','id')->rules('nullable','digits:20' )->sortable()->nullable()->hideFromIndex(),
```

while updating the data if the numbers are more that it should throw an error like `Max 20 digits allowed`, now i want to give the length dynamically ,How to do that one

How i am trying

```
$length=25;

 Text::make('TrackID','id')->rules('nullable',digits:$this->length )->sortable()->nullable()->hideFromIndex(),
```

Now the error is Max $this->length allowed , please help me to set the length dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one more way is there for doing the same thing

```
->rules('nullable',"digits:.$this->length")
```

I tested in my local it's working fine ,i hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need the 'digits' rule to remain a string, so it should still have quotes around it.
2. It looks like you are setting the length into a variable called `$length` rather than `$this->length`, so you need to consume it the same.

```php
$length=25;

 Text::make('TrackID','id')
->rules('nullable','digits:'.$length)
->sortable()
->nullable()
->hideFromIndex(),
```

There are a couple of important concepts at play here. I encourage you to study these resources as a great way to continue your journey:

Variable scope - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

String concatenation - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Thanks alot it's working fine